# Gerrit Prolog Rule - Require specific file type

Tags: prolog, gerrit

I am new to Gerrit and Prolog, and am having difficulty creating my rule. With the rules.pl I currently have, it stalls when I try to open the Gerrit window after running the push command.

What I'd like is to make a rule that at each push to the remote, a .txt file needs to be present in the list of changed files. I saw a similar rule in the Prolog cookbook, but mine is not correct yet. Here's what I have currently (have made some changes in the last 24hours):

```
    submit_rule(S) :-
            gerrit:default_submit(X),
            X = .. [submit | Ls],
            my_rule(Ls,R),
            S = .. [submit | R].

    my_rule(S1,T) :-
            gerrit:commit_delta('\\.txt$),
            T = label('Text-File-Must-Be-Present',ok(T)).

    my_rule(S1,[label('Text-File-Must-Be-Present',need(_)) | S1]).
```

I think I am still missing something in my_rule. I need to be sure that commit_delta returned true. If not, then it should return false and block the push to the remote repo. Do I need something more like this?

```
    gerrit:commit_delta('\\.txt$),
    T \= false, !,
    T = label('Text-File-Must-Be-Present',ok(T)).
```

in order to return if false is returned? Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Don't know gerrit, but you have several syntax problems, maybe induced by some buggy text processing step:

```
gerrit:commit_delta('\\.txt$),
```

left the atom unterminated, hiding the subsequent bug (at least in Prologs not supporting SWI-Prolog extensions of compounds with 0 arity)

```
T = label('Text-File-Must-Be-Present',need()).
```

`need()` should have at least 1 argument, or should be written down as `need`.

If gerrit implements its own Prolog interpreter, it should be able to show somewhere an error report...

BTW, the first rule is more complex than needed. I would write

```
submit_rule(submit(R)) :-
    gerrit:default_submit(R,submit(Ls)),
    my_rule(R).
```

clearly showing you're forgetting to process `Ls`

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have updated the original post with some changes that a Prolog-familiar friend suggested. I don't understand your first comment though. Doesn't the comma say to continue checking?

Comment: no, the comma it's either - an argument separator - the 'and' operator (when used in a predicate) - list elements separator. I cannot recall other usage ...